# innodb 5.7 INSERT INTO Error 1785: Statement violates GTID consistency

Tags: mysql, innodb

Recently I had to switch from innon 5.5 to 5.7 and faced such a problem, rummaged through a bunch of documentation and it seems to me that this query needs to be done via INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
Am I right, please tell me where to look.
Thanks in advance!

> Error 1785: Statement violates GTID consistency: Updates to non-transactional tables can only be done in either autocommitted statements or single-statement transactions, and never in the same statement as updates to transactional tables.

```
INSERT INTO `a_m` (` p_s`, `a_id`,` pu`, `а_in_r_c`,` f_a_c`, `t_a_c`,` a_in_a_c`, `e_ra`,` created_dt`, `accepted_dt`,` s`, `c`,` fi`, `ps_r_id`,` e_d`, `r_r`,` r_r_t`, `a_u`,` b_in`, `md5`,` is_us_v`, `m_id`,` tr_id`, `mt_o `,` c_cf_a_id`) 
VALUES ('NEW', '1', NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, '0', '2021-02-09T07: 21: 12Z', NULL, 'new', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-gtids.html#sysvar_enforce_gtid_consistency

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I realized that I can disable --enforce-gtid-consistency. But then all operations can break GTID consistency. How can this affect future database queries? Will this lead to errors?